# ogr2ogr libcurl error in Mac OS

Tags: php, macos, curl, libcurl, dylib

I am working to run "ogr2ogr" command in terminal.
I got this error message.

> dyld: Library not loaded: libcurl.4.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/bin/ogr2ogr   Reason: Incompatible library version: ogr2ogr
>   requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version
>   7.0.0

There is a mismatch between the system requirement and library requirement. As I can tell, the latest curl is version 7 http://curl.haxx.se/download.html,
why is this asking for version 8? I also tried to upgrade curl with brew
but couldn't symlink into /usr/local, because would cause conflicts with
the OS.

In order to figure this problem: I started by figuring out if the Curl is used by different

$$ Which curl
/usr/bin/curl

I installed GDAL on mac by fellowing these instructions ([StackOverFlow Post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34360/ecw-mrsid-plugin-for-gdal-from-kyngchaos-not-working-on-mountain-lion)). 
To explore where the ogr2ogr is, I run the command.
$$ which ogr2ogr
/usr/local/bin/ogr2ogr

I fellowed these instructions :

> 1. Download curl sources: http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.25.0.zip
> 2. Unarchive the zip file somewhere
> 3. Open a Terminal window and go to the directory containing curl sources
> 4. Type: CFLAGS=-m64 ./configure
> 5. Type: make
> 6. Type: sudo make install

[Source](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?230882-appleseed-renderer-%28now-with-experimental-Blender-exporter!%29&p=2098867&viewfull=1#post2098867) :

But it doesn't work out.

Another approach 
I downloaded [this file](http://appleseedhq.net/stuff/libcurl.4.dylib-7.0.0.zip), unzip it into the bin/ directory, but when I tried to run it. I got this problem

```
../../bin/libcurl.4.dylib: cannot execute binary fil
```

There is one answer I found that seems very helpful, but I couldn't find it very practical.

> If you didn't define the --with-curl option when running GDAL
>   ./configure, then 
>       GDAL will link with the curl library indicated by "curl-config --libs"
>       You likley have several libcurl on your system and the one that got used when 
>       linking GDAL is not the one available at runtime.
>       The 8.0.0 or 7.0.0 don't necessarily reflect the "human readable" version of 
>       the curl library. It might be some other numbering scheme related to how the 
>       API/ABI of the library evolves, or something linked to packaging.

How can we do that in a practical way.

I read many articles before posting this question here, Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this out?

[Python Anaconda linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124968/python-anaconda-linking)

I did that, then simlinked some stuff:

```
ln -s libcurl.4.0.0.dylib libcurl.3.dylib
```

Another error came up, now pertaining to libxml2.

I did:

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
brew link --force libxml2 libxslt
```

And now ogr2ogr is finally working